# GitHub cannot push folder, submodules issue?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I cannot seem to push a folder to GitHub.  It's listed as a "submodule" I think that's what the non-clickable folder icon means however I cannot seem to remove this  or resolve this.  Does anyone have any ideas?

[There is no .git folder or anything that references a sub module.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIBd1.png)

Images:

[This is the view on GitHub, the folder has a different icons and is not clickable.  From research this is a sub module but I'm sure why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBofV.png)

Answer (score 0):

A submodule is another repository that is linked into your main repository.

If you change the files inside, you first need to go inside this folder (or open this folder as a separate repository in a GUI tool), and commit/push from there. The commit will target that other repository, not your own.

After that you need to modify the link in your main repo so that it points to the new commit. This is done by normal "git add _submodule_folder_", "git commit", "git push".